# Why can't I get the connecting client's ip address on my server running Node.js + Websocket hosted by Openshift (Using WebSocket-Node)

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, openshift

I'm using Node.js 0.10 + WebSocket-Node ([Seen here](https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node)) hosted by openshift  and thats pretty much it, i'm not using express.  Other than being unable to get any connecting client's ip address the server is otherwise behaving exactly as intended and processing websocket requests and connections wonderfully.

I've done my homework and I know openshift is behind a reverse proxy and the x-forwarded-for header should be consulted for the correct ip.  However the WebSocketRequest.remoteAddress property, (which is meant to take its returned ip from the X-Forwarded-For header if  its present,) returns the value of OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP (as listed in rhc env), which is presumably the server's ip.  Furthermore i've manually gone through the WebSocketRequest.httpRequest object, (which is meant to be a reference to the original Node HTTP request object) and can't find any trace of the x-forwarded-for header in there, (Though I won't pretend to be anywhere near knowledgable enough to understand what I did see in there.)

My server also processes standard HTTP requests which **DO** return the clients ip when I check request.headers['x-forwarded-for'], sadly this doesn't help get the IP's of clients connected via websocket though, as they do not trigger a standard HTTP response.

I must be missing something here and would be extremely grateful for any new routes of investigation or cunning workarounds anyone can offer.

Answer (score 0):

You could probe each client for its ip address upon socket connection.
You could use something like : http://jsonip.com/?callback 
the jsonip.com request returns the following object :

```
{"ip":"XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX","about":"/about","Pro!":"http://getjsonip.com"}
```

Even thou trusting clients isn't always the best approach,
here you have a client-side example of the probe scenario :

```
socket.on('PROBE', function(){
        $.getJSON('http://jsonip.com/?callback=?', function(r){ 
            var myIP = r.ip;
            socket.emit('C_IP', myIP);
        });
```

**Heres my experience with node.js & socket.io @ OpenShift.**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29285652/2976093