# How to detect the Remote/Client IP Address of a WebSocket connection on OpenShift

Tags: http, websocket, openshift

In the OpenShift cloud, the usual Apache proxy will send the HTTP headers `x-client-ip` and `x-forwarded-for`, which I can use to determine the client IP.

But for the [newer proxy, which is the only option for WebSocket users](https://blog.openshift.com/paas-websockets/), these are the only sent headers:

- `connection`
- `upgrade`
- `sec-websocket-version`
- `sec-websocket-key`
- `origin`
- `host`

None of these headers can help me to detect the remote address and `socket.remoteAddress`'s NodeJS property is useless, as it will detect the proxy IP.

Any solution I can use?

Answer (score 2):

### Heres my experience with ***node.js*** & **socket.io** @ OpenShift.

I had to find a way around **socket.handshake.address**, it wouldn't work as expected, so this was my implementation for logging client.ip address ...

When a *client* connects, the *server* 'asks' for client.ip with a packet. **0x00**

When the **0x00** packet reaches the *client* :

```
socket.on('0x00', function(){
        $.getJSON('http://jsonip.com/?callback=?', function(r){ 
            var myIP = r.ip;
            socket.emit('0x01', myIP);
        });
```

Sending the **0x01** packet containing the client.ip to the *server*.

This would be an example of the server receiving packet **0x01** :

```
socket.on('0x01', function(myIP){
    console.log('[+] Client @',myIP,':',socket.id);
  });
```

This works perfect for me, good luck with your implementation.